# My React js setstate doent work can you help me for this

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, vite

Hi guys i am learning reactjs and i have some problem with this code. As you i have setSliderData code, my response data is not null but setSliderData appear empty when write down on console. Why sliderData is empty. How can i solve this problem.

````
import axios from "axios";


export interface SliderData{
    id:number;
    sliderTitle:string;
    sliderDescription:string;
    sliderImgUrl:string;
    sliderNo:number;
}
function EditSliderPage(){

    const [sliderData,setSliderData]=useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function getData() {
          try {
            const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/getData?tableName=sliderTable');
            console.log(response.data);
            setSliderData(response.data);
            console.log(sliderData);
        } catch (error) {
            
            console.error('Error fetching data', error);
          }
        }
        getData();
      }, []);

    return ( <>


<div className="flex-slide home"  style={{backgroundImage:"url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1711026964454-c7729453cba0?q=80&w=1374&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D)"}}>
  <div className="flex-title flex-title-home" id="flex-title">Özel Diyet Programları</div>
  <div className="flex-about flex-about-home">
    <p>Click here to navigate to the home section of the website</p>
  </div>
</div>


    
    </> );
}

export default EditSliderPage;```
````

Comment: Hey, please move " console.log(sliderData);" to outside useEffect function. It should be in the main scope of the component, so you`ll probably be able to see the desired effect.

Comment: There's no error here. It's just that setSliderData doesn't take effect immediately hence it will display empty. If you move it outside of the useEffect, you will see that it sets correctly